# Is this proof correct for congruences?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

I am new to proving math theorems and not sure that my proof is correct so can anyone please tell me if its correct or not and why ?

> **The problem :** Let $m_1 , m_2 ,\ldots, m_n $ be pairwise relatively prime integers greater than or equal to 2. Show that if $a \equiv b \ \pmod{m_i}$ for $i = 1, 2,\ldots, n$,  then $a \equiv b \pmod{m}$ where $m = m_1 m_2 \cdots m_n$

**Note** : I can't use CRT as this problem is to proof it .

**My proof:**

> because  $a \equiv b\pmod{m_i}$ therefore $m_i |\,a-b $
>
> therefore $a-b = c_i \, m_i$,  therefore $(a-b)^n = c\,m$
>
> therefore $m \ |\ (a-b)^n$   therefore $m \ |\ ((a-b)^n + b^n) - b^n$
>
> therefore $(a-b)^n + b^n \equiv b^n \pmod m$
>
> therefore $(a-b)^n \equiv 0 \pmod m$
>
> because $(a-b)$ is a possible solution to the congruence, therefore
> $(a-b)\equiv 0 \pmod m$
>
> therefore $a \equiv b \pmod m$

Comment: Central to your argument is the claim $$x^n\equiv 0 \pmod m \implies x\equiv 0 \pmod m.$$ Unfortunately this is false for many $m$.  Instead, I would focus on $n=2$ (the case of general $n$ will follow by a simple induction afterwards) and perhaps use a characterization of "pairwise relatively prime" more prominently in your proof.

Comment: so is there is any way to fix it or i need to build another proof ?

Comment: There's not a way to repair that claim as far as I can see, so my vote is for "build another" (I gave some hints to a common proof in my last comment)

Comment: I also don't get $a-b=c_im_i\,\Rightarrow\,(a-b)^n=cm$. Why should the other relatively prime factors appear here? Ok it's just unclear as a proof step. Additionally $m\mid(a-b)^n$ already means $(a-b)^n=cm$ directly without running circles with $b^n$

Comment: **A more explicit hint:** Show that $m_2 \mid c_1$.  Then use induction to show that $m_2m_3\cdots m_n \mid c_1$.  At every step you will likely need to utilize the assumption that the $m_1, m_2, \ldots, m_n$ are pairwise relatively prime.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the powers.  They make things messy and aren't relevant.

$a\equiv b \pmod {m_i}$ then $m_i| a-b$

so if *all* the $m_i|a-b$ and the $m_i$ are relatively prime then $m=\prod m_i|a-b$.

so $a\equiv b \pmod m$.

That's all there is to it.

I guess the only thing to worry about $d|k$ and $e|k$ then $\operatorname{lcm}(e,d)|k$.  But I'm assuming you have or can prove that.